# Initialization of parameters of Bayesian Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, bayesian, variational-bayes, weight-initialization

What is the best practice to initialize parameters of the Bayesian Neural Network? I am stuck in a situation where I don’t initialize the parameters and every time I run the variational inference, I get different training errors (varies between 2-7%) and parameters. I am looking for stable results, basically the same result every time I run the complete variational inference. I was hoping to get the same training error, at least when I ran the model. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: unfortunately, even in much simpler models than Neural nets, variational inference is known to suffer from many local optima. If you find out a solution, do share it with the rest of us!